# TypeError when passing raw_input to modulo operator

Tags: python, if-statement, typeerror, python-2.x, modulo

Sorry, I haven't programmed in python for a while.  I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

when I attempt to run

```
n = raw_input('Enter any natural number: ');
if n % 10 == 0:
    o = n / 10;
    print(o);
else:
    o = n * 5 + 5;
    print(o);
```

I am struggling to understand why.  I know this will be very simple and idiotic...

Answer (score 4):

n is a string. You will need to convert it to an `int`

`n = int(raw_input('Enter any natural number: '));`

Answer (score -1):

Here i have solved the issue of your code :

```
n = int(input('Enter any natural number: '))
if (n % 10 == 0):
    o = n / 10;
    print(o);
else:
    o = n * 5 + 5;
    print(o);
```

[image: output]

I think this is your desirable output .